# Changing DT_WSTR to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: excel, date, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am using SSIS to import data from Excel to SQL table.
The Excel files have a date column of the data type DT_WSTR, and I use a data conversion to change the column to DT_Timestamp, but SSIS puts the month in place day and day in a month place and some rows, it remains the same as the excel files.

Below is a screenshot of the January 2021 date column table in SQL, and the date format is YYYY-MM-DD, so the month's value should only be 01.

[image]

Comment: What does your input string look like?

Comment: @Hana can you share your data conversion?

Comment: I would run the input string thru a script component and use DataTime.ParseExact()